# Cannot remove files in Cygwin on Windows 10

Tags: bash, cygwin

I just installed Cygwin on a new Windows 10 machine. I get an error "Invalid request code" whenever I try to remove a file. However every other file operation that I have tested so far seems to work fine.

```
sbaker@FWA002495 ~ >$ echo "testing" > foo
sbaker@FWA002495 ~ >$ ls -l foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 sbaker LOGFWA+Group(513) 8 Apr 20 12:51 foo
sbaker@FWA002495 ~ >$ cat foo
testing
sbaker@FWA002495 ~ >$ rm -f foo
rm: cannot remove 'foo': Invalid request code
sbaker@FWA002495 ~ >$ mv foo bar
sbaker@FWA002495 ~ >$ rm -f bar
rm: cannot remove 'bar': Invalid request code
sbaker@FWA002495 ~ >$ which rm
/usr/bin/rm
```

The files can be removed without any issues from file explorer or from a cmd prompt. Files that I make through file explorer or through a cmd behave the same way (can be read/appended/renamed/moved correctly in Cygwin, but not deleted. They also have the same user/group).

The problem is not limited to the 'rm' command. For example, when editing a file with vim, it is unable to delete the swap file.

A possibly interesting side note is that clobbering appears to work fine:

```
sbaker@FWA002495 ~/test >$ echo "test1" > foo
sbaker@FWA002495 ~/test >$ echo "test2" > bar
sbaker@FWA002495 ~/test >$ ls -l
total 2
-rw-r--r-- 1 sbaker LOGFWA+Group(513) 6 Apr 20 13:07 bar
-rw-r--r-- 1 sbaker LOGFWA+Group(513) 6 Apr 20 13:07 foo
sbaker@FWA002495 ~/test >$ mv -f foo bar
sbaker@FWA002495 ~/test >$ ls -l
total 1
-rw-r--r-- 1 sbaker LOGFWA+Group(513) 6 Apr 20 13:07 bar
sbaker@FWA002495 ~/test >$ cat bar
test1
```

So files *can* be removed, just not in the ordinary way. I'm not sure what that means, if anything.

---

Update 4/22/2020:

I wrote a simple C application to test removing files:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    int r = unlink("testing");
    printf("RESULT: %d (%d)\n", r, errno );
    perror("err");

return r;
}
```

When I build this with cc under Cygwin and run it, I get:

```
$ ./test1
RESULT: -1 (54)
err: Invalid request code
```

I also get the same result if I run this executable from a Windows CMD prompt.
So apparently it has something to do with Cygwin itself, and not the shell environment.

---

Update 4/23/2020:

icacls output for a test file

```
$ icacls $(cygpath -wa foo)
C:\cygwin64\home\sbaker\foo LOGFWA\sbaker:(R,W,D,WDAC,WO)
                            LOGFWA\Domain Users:(R)
                            Everyone:(R)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

The strace output is long, but this is the first part that differs from an strace of a successful command on my old Win7 machine:

```
  101  188506 [main] rm 1688 _unlink_nt: Trying to delete \??\C:\cygwin64\home\sbaker\foo, isdir = 0
  249  188755 [main] rm 1688 _unlink_nt: \??\C:\cygwin64\home\sbaker\foo, return status = 0xC0000002
  102  188857 [main] rm 1688 seterrno_from_nt_status: /home/corinna/src/cygwin/cygwin-3.1.4/cygwin-3.1.4-1.x86_64/src/newlib-cygwin/winsup/cygwin/syscalls.cc:1116 status 0xC0000002 -> wind
ows error 1
  144  189001 [main] rm 1688 geterrno_from_win_error: windows error 1 == errno 54
   97  189098 [main] rm 1688 unlink: -1 = unlink(/home/sbaker/foo), errno 54
```

---

Update 4/30/2020:

I am also having somewhat similar problems using WSL.

In PowerShell, I get:

```
PS C:\Users\sbaker> wsl
sbaker@FWA002495 /mnt/c/Users/sbaker $ touch foo
sbaker@FWA002495 /mnt/c/Users/sbaker $ rm foo
rm: remove regular empty file 'foo'? y
rm: cannot remove 'foo': Function not implemented
```

I also tried installing Ubuntu on Windows (20.04 LTS) from the Microsoft Store. When running that, I can successfully remove files from the Linux file space (/home/sbaker), but if I try to remove files from /mnt/c I get the same errors:

```
PS C:\Users\sbaker> wsl
sbaker@FWA002495 /mnt/c/Users/sbaker $ touch foo
sbaker@FWA002495 /mnt/c/Users/sbaker $ rm foo
rm: remove regular empty file 'foo'? y
rm: cannot remove 'foo': Function not implemented
```

Comment: Do you have any other cygwin based software installed? gitbash for example? or mingwbash?

Comment: No, nothing else is installed at all except for antivirus and VPN software (other than default apps installed with Windows 10)

Comment: `Invalid request code` is a message coming from the Cygwin DLL. Check ACL of the directory with windows `icacls` for some hint on any permissions issue. You can also run `strace /usr/bin/rm.exe foo` for more details

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have updated the issue with the output of icacls and a portion of the strace log

Comment: Currently it is required for my work setup. I am just moving my setup from Win7->Win10 and hopefully can move to WSL in the future, but I need to get my old workflow going ASAP.

Comment: check the ACLS of the directory as it can add hint. The one of `foo` are normal ones. I see two possibilities: #1 a software is interfering as the error message `Invalid request code` is very unusual for the operation; I would expect a normal `Access denied`. #2 Your W10 has some new unusual setting. See https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.using.bloda for #1 and you can also ask support on the mailing list https://cygwin.com/lists.html for #2

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas  Cygwin works fine on W10. WSL is not yet a replacement and it is moving to a more traditional VM with WSL2.

Comment: @matzeri.  I do 100% of my c linux code under WSL and WSL2 is **nothing like** a "traditional vm".  I myself used (bloated and slow) Cygwin for many MANY years until WSL made more sense.  You shouldn't make comments about something you clearly know nothing about.

Comment: @matzeri Thank you for those resources. I will check with the mailing list.

Comment: Everyone: Please don't clutter this question with a discussion of the merits of Cygwin vs WSL. At this time I do not have an option of using anything except Cygwin. 

However, I also am having very similar problems removing files using WSL. I will add notes above about that, in case it gives any insight into the issue with Cygwin.